# How to cut file name in grep output (awk, sed)?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

Hello I have an output from grep

```
cc.log.1:<Operation adaptorMethod="search" adaptorName="Search" status="Success"/>
cc.log.12:<Operation adaptorMethod="getOrderId" adaptorName="PersistenceAdaptor" status="Success"/>
```

I need to cut off file name from beginning and leave only tag

I tried  several variants of `awk '/<Operation/,/>$/'`  `sed -n '/^<Ope/,/>$/p'` and etc

But have no success. Could anyone help me?

Comment: If it comes from `grep` and you have the file name, post the `grep` command because maybe you are using one parameter that is not necessary.

Comment: You don't need grep or sed if you are using awk. Post a sample of the input to grep, tell us what you want to extract from that, and post the final expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `sed`, `awk` or `cut` you just want the `-h` option of `grep`:

```
-h, --no-filename

Suppress  the  prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when 
there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.
```